# How to scanf input to 256 bit unsigned char array for AES key

Tags: c, input, openssl, scanf, unsigned-char

I am attempting to prompt user input for a string of 32 characters (256 bits) to be read into an unsigned char array. I plan to use this unsigned char array for a 256 bit AES encryption key using openSSL. The openSSL documentation mentions the length must be correct. Currently I have tried this:

```
void input(unsigned char* key){
    scanf("%32c", key);
}

unsigned char key[32];
input(key);

size_t keysize = strlen(key);
printf("%zu\n", keysize);
```

Output:

```
33
```

I believe it should be exactly 32. If I reduce the scanf option to "%31c" it outputs 31. This is likely an issue with the terminator character at the end of an array but I am unsure how to fix it.

This is how they create it in the documentation:

```
/* A 256 bit key */
unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"01234567890123456789012345678901";
```

This outputs 32 when I print its strlen(). How can I make my user input read in to an unsigned char array of the correct size?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I fixed the typo, sorry.

Comment: `strlen(key)` expects `key` is a _string_.  `scanf("%32c", key);` does not form a _string_ as `key` likely is missing a _null character_.  Result: _undefined behavior_.  Still recommend a [mcve]